# How to get the position of picture boxes after moving them with panel in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a siutation  in which I need to move all the picture boxes. I have 100 boxes 60 for Roll Number and rest of them for paper code.

**Issue**

I have two panels in my form. panel1 is for reference means where pictures boxes must be and other panel (PnlAnswersheet) is in which i have 100 picture boxes. Issue is X and Y locations of "PnlAnswersheet" starts from 0,0 which I don't want

**Requirement**

in code. I want the locations as Pictureboxes are virtually the elements of panel1 (Panel which is the parent panel of PnlAnswersheet over which PnelAnswersheet should move).

Here is my sample code for above situation:

```
 if (index1== "1")
        {

            x = pb1.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb1.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }
if (index2== "2")
        {

            x = pb2.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb2.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }

if (index3== "3")
        {

            x = pb3.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb3.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }

if (index4== "4")
        {

            x = pb4.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb4.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }

if (index5== "5")
        {

            x = pb5.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb5.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }
if (index5== "6")
        {

            x = pb6.Location.X+panel1.Location.X;
            y = pb6.Location.Y+panel1.Location.Y;
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x, y, 53, 37);
     }
```

Belwo I attached pictures for problem and requirement:

**Porblem:**

[image]

**requirement**
[image]

Comment: Do look into [Control.PointToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Control.PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Or simply  Point.Offset(Point)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the page offset to the origin of the `FillEllipse` command

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, x + <distance from edge>, y + <distance from top>, 53, 37);
```

Where the distance is the offset you need.

Comment: THanks. Can u please elaborate?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said?